# Upload data to MAX 7219

Tags: c

I have the following code to write data on MAX7219 for light up a 8x8 LED Matrix:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {          
    CLK = LOW;      
    DIN = temp & MSBIT >> i;
    CLK = HIGH;
}
```

The thing is, sadly, I just know that the code line (`DIN = temp & MSBIT >> i;`), must be exactly like that, otherwise the LED´s won't show the expected, but I don't understand how it works...

Please, I really need explanation because I'm stuck....

Note: variable "temp" is always a hexadecimal number like 0x20, and "MSBIT" = 0x80.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not complete so it's not possible to give a detail answer. Please provide full minimal running example and tell us something about the platform you are working on. For example the variable "temp" has not been declared or defined within your code snippet.
First you have to know something about operator precdence. Have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

You can use this online gcc compiler to run and debug small test applications to test the behaviour of your code line. http://pythontutor.com/c.html

So I guess DIN is a register of a peripheral. You assign a value to this register. This value is a bit wise "AND" operation result from a the variable temp and MSBIT ("Maybe a constant") shifted i bits the the right. 
So to make the expression more clear you can also write: `DIN = temp & (MSBIT >> i).`

For closer details about how the MAX7210 is working have a look here. 
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/8x8-led-matrix-max7219-tutorial-scrolling-text-android-control-via-bluetooth/

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess:

`CLK`:  Clock out pin of your microcontroller
`DIN`:  Data out pin of your microcontroller

So you are shifting out the value in `temp` bit by bit on `DIN` with a clock signal on `CLK`.

```
i = 0  -> DIN = bit 7 of temp  
i = 1  -> DIn = bit 6 of temp  
...  
i = 7  -> DIN = bit 0 of temp
```